# How can I implement a flight seat layout using Swing?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jframe, jbutton

I am working on a airline ticket reservation system in Java and I need a `JFrame` with seat layout of a flight. My idea is to set multiple `JButton` controls which represent seats and when a button is clicked that seat is assigned to a user. But the problem is the buttons representing the seats which are already booked should be disabled.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: Simple....don't disable the buttons. Instead, change their background color. One color for seat unbooked, another color for seat booked, another color for seat empty, another color for seat full, another color for seat with actual leg room, and yet another color for seat with no leg room and you're packed in there like sardines. :( Have a legend visible.